# Why is css is adding a duplicate border to my element when hovered?

Tags: html, css

Expected result: the active link has a black bottom border. when hovering over links (not including the active page) the bottom bar is shown with a different color.

Actual result: the black bottom border appears under the active page link, but when hovering over the link it remains and a second, colored bottom border appears.

I was using similar code to control background color and it worked fine. But when I switched to trying to use bottom-border, I got an unexpected result -

Two bottom borders appear, one black and one colored.

```css
ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #61a5c2;
}

ul.topnav li.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Diagnosis</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Data Visualization</a></li>
      <li class="right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: insert your html, pls

Comment: Something like a playground link would substantially simplify debugging for us.

Comment: What is your expected result? You weren't clear about that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your css to below. "active" class is on li so this check will make sure if the black border is there then do not put border on hover. so :not(.active) will be on li

```
ul.topnav li:not(.active) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #61a5c2;
}
```

```css
ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent
}

ul.topnav li:not(.active) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #61a5c2;
}

ul.topnav li.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
<ul class="topnav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">Diagnosis</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">Data Visualization</a></li>
  <li class="right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion and it does result in only one bottom border appearing as desired, however for some reason the active page border and the hover border are not aligned - one is below the other. Is there any way to resolve this? [image](https://imgur.com/a/Dh2PnP3)

Comment: @DylanCairns what is border-bottom: 2px solid transparent line doing ? is it required ? This may be one reason they are not alligning.

Comment: That fixed it! That line was originally included because the content below the navbar would move depending on wether an item was hovered or not. The objective was to prevent that. But I see it was causing the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, if I got you right, you want all your `li > a`s have a colored bottom border when hovered except your active `a` which should keep it's black bottom border; you're problem was in declaring your selector for your active `li`, you need to hit `ul.topnav li.active a{ border-bottom: 2px solid black; }`, which indicates to the `a` of the active `li` not the `li` itself, and also you should change `ul.topnav li:not(.active) a:hover` to `ul .topnav li a:hover {border-bottom: 2px solid #61a5c2;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:
A link is active, so the list item is given a bottom border because of this code:

```
ul.topnav li.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black
}
```

Now lets hover on the anchor tag of this active link. You are not adding any "active" class to the anchor tag. so on hover the following code is applied always for all anchor tags:

```
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #61a5c2;
}
```

so you end up seeing both borders. Change the selector for hover styles to make this work.